# Is there religion on 24th century Earth?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In Star Trek, is there any evidence that any sort of religion is still practiced on Earth or on any Human world?

There are other species of the Federation that do still praise a god of sorts, eg. The Klingons with Kahless. But I haven't heard any specific mention of anyone on Earth or on board the Enterprise practicing any sort of religion.

Was religion just one of those ideas that mankind 'grew out of' so to speak, by the time of the 24th century?